# Openshift app redirecting to https://domain_name/app

Tags: http-status-code-404, redhat, openshift, cname

I have hosted an app on Redhat Open shift. I didn't change anything but it started redirecting to https://www.plovist.com/app and throwing 404 error. 
Can anyone help me in solving this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I logged into Godaddy(my DNS) account and found out that in Cnames(Alias) `www` wasn't pointing to  `mydjango-plovist.rhcloud.com`(URL given by Openshift).
Also I pinged `mydjango-plovist.rhcloud.com` and it gave a different IP Address than one I had written in A Record. 
So I pointed in Cname to `mydjango-plovist.rhcloud.com` and in A Record pointed www to new IP Address I got after pinging `mydjango-plovist.rhcloud.com`.
**My app started**
So Openshift changed their IP Address without telling the users. And also there was some problem in my Godaddy Account.

Comment: So that's how it works... You need to ping your app first and Openshift can change the IP without further notice.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't have GoDaddy forwarding to your IP. You should forward `example.com` to `www.example.com`, then create a CNAME alias from `www.example.com` to `app-domain.rhcloud.com`. This means the IP can change and your forwarding won't be affected.

Comment: Luc has it right. The answer above is correct, but misses the point that cloud services like Openshift should *never* be accessed by their IP addresses as these are subject to change.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that you have correctly added your alias to your application (www.plovist.com)

Comment: I read one openshift post about the issue I'm facing and deleted my alias and added it again. Still it's not working. Will it take some time and I need to restart my app? Can there be some issue on the Domain Name provider's side? On default address my site is working : http://mydjango-plovist.rhcloud.com/concept/

Comment: Looks like you are using some kind of redirect service for your cname (www.plovist.com) which makes it really hard to troubleshoot, the cname should point to your app-domain.rhcloud.com  corey-redhat:~ cdaley$ host www.plovist.com
www.plovist.com is an alias for plovist.com.
plovist.com has address 50.17.8.22

Comment: I have added plovist.com and www.plovist.com as alias.

Comment: I still don't think whatever service you are redirecting through is working correctly, how is it setup?

Comment: In my .htaccess file i'm doing 
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]`

Comment: I mean your dns is not pointing to your openshift gear, you are using some kind of redirection service

Comment: No I don't think so. It was working fine for 1 year, what happened suddenly. I didn't touch my DNS zone file too. I think problem lies in resolving of Openshift myapp.rhcloud.com to Ip address.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem and solved by just **restarting** the openshift application.
After that everythink work as expected.

See also this guide for information on how to change CNAME and create an alias.

https://blog.openshift.com/custom-url-names-for-your-paas-applications-host-forwarding-and-cnames-the-openshift-way/

Comment: Thanks! I confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue today after some cname changes.
For me it helped to **flush the dns chache**

> ipconfig /flushdns

Answer (score 0):

Do anything suggested before or just patiently wait for a hour and check.
I think it is just temporary problem of DNS servers. 
I am sure not only in my case :)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it after 2 hours.
The issue was, i was missing "www." in openshift alias domain settings. (previously it was domain.com instead of www.domain.com)

I entered www.domain.com and after updating wordpress siteurl/home settings it worked fine.

These comments really helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26337432/385377