# Point domain and subdomain to OpenShift app with CloudFlare

Tags: wordpress, dns, openshift, cloudflare

I've got a Wordpress site running on OpenShift. My DNS settings are handled by CloudFlare. I would like to have both mydomain.nl and www.mydomain.nl to point to my app at mydomain-app.rhcloud.com. I've two CNAME records setup in CloudFlare to do just that:

(1) CNAME mydomain.nl -> mydomain-app.rhcloud.com

(2) CNAME www -> mydomain-app.rhcloud.com

In OpenShift both mydomain.nl and www.mydomain.nl are configured as aliasses.

Now, mydomain.nl works fine but for some reason www.mydomain.nl won't be resolved and ends in a loop. A host lookup returns the same IPv4 and IPv6 addresses for both mydomain.nl and www.mydomain.nl.

I've looked around quite a bit; people with a comparable setup seem to do the same as I do but apparently I'm missing something..?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

In CloudFlare, each of the websites you have configured has "Page Rules". I missed this earlier on in [dns-settings-openshift-with-cloudflare-rhcloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329211/dns-settings-openshift-with-cloudflare-rhcloud).

I've now added a permanent (301) forwarding rule as such:

```
http://www.mydomain.nl/* -> http://mydomain.nl/$1
```

Which solved the problem.