# Point my naked domain name to an OpenShift application with cloudflare

Tags: dns, openshift, cloudflare

In OpenShift both mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com are configured as aliasses of myapp-rhcloud.com. Same for cloudflare.

I tried with the following coment: [DNS settings openshift cloudflare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26337432/5486953)

'www.mydomain.com' work fine, but the naked domain 'mydomain.com' redirects me to an error page that says: "The connection is not private. It is possible that unauthorized users are trying to steal your information" the Link change from example.com to https:// example.com/app with the 'https' denied.

Also an icon appears next to the CNAME in CloudFlare:

"Flattening CNAME will be applied to this record since root (ie apex) CNAME records are limited by the DNS specification." I dont understand that.

I modified the rules in cloudflare like this:

redirects "http:// example.com/*" to "http:// www.example.com/$1"
with '301' for the redirect type

I'm missing something?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. This is more hosting/dns, which is a server-side thing.

Comment: Do you have a page forwarding rule setup in CloudFlare to redirect naked domain to www subdomain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few days my page example.com it worked. The link in my question works right, the problem was that CloudFlare took 4 days to establish the rules associated in the CNAME.

In conclusion... just wait.

Comment: CloudFlare doesn't take 4 days to register a DNS change. Sounds like there was a different issue. Would be curious what else you may have changed in that period of time.

Comment: I just follow all steps in my first question, when i dont find any answer I started working on other things without changing anything about DNS and after three days, the domain worked well as by magic.

Maybe it could have been associated with the domain had previously been managed by hosting24 and during those 4 days, I was in the process of migration to cloudflare.

Comment: Indeed, according to [CloadFlare's docs](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205195708-Step-3-Change-your-domain-name-servers-to-Cloudflare): "it may take up to 72 hours for the name server information to propagate". Also your concern about CNAME flattening is unnecessary. They only tell you that use custom improvement in DNS resolution - more details [here](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cname-flattening-rfc-compliant-cnames-at-a-domains-root/).